# DevOps Center: Retroactively removing metadata

Tags: devopscenter

We've started using DevOps Center to manage our development pipeline. Since it's early days, there's been some slippage, and some changes have been deployed to production without going through the new DevOps Center process... oops.

I'm trying to get our GitHub repo up to speed with these changes, but there are destructive changes in the mix. If I create a Work Item and try to promote it through the pipeline, I get a deployment error associated with `destructiveChanges.xml` -- basically it tells me I can't delete something from Salesforce (and therefore, my repo branch) that doesn't exist in Salesforce currently.

I realize I could manually re-add the deleted metadata back into my various environments as a workaround before deleting it again via DevOps Center, but this approach seems slow and messy to me.

Are any of the following possible?

- Commit these changes directly to my DevOps Center-linked branches outside of DevOps Center (without confusing DevOps Center and causing my pipeline to crash and burn)

**...OR...**

- Use DevOps Center to promote these changes, but somehow get it to skip the whole deployment-to-Salesforce part

Comment: Similar issue here. No idea how to proceed yet

Comment: Yep, same issue here - I've not yet found a good solution.  I ended up having to manually create the deleted items in each pipeline stage, such that it can then be successfully deleted - go figure!